# Changing the default language of my Dutch Windows 7 to English

Tags: windows-7, language-pack

I have a Dutch language version of Windows 7 and downloaded English language packages for it, but there is no way to use them.

Do I have to install an English version of Windows 7 instead in order for them to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows 7 Ultimate, you can switch languages through the control panel. Otherwise you'll either have to upgrade to Ultimate edition (E.g. using [Anytime Upgrade](http://windows.microsoft.com/nl-NL/windows7/products/windows-anytime-upgrade)) or reinstall Windows 7 using an English version.